# update statement getting an error

Tags: php

Parse error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';' in ds.php on line 6
```

This is my code

```
include_once("db_conn.php");
 $del=$_GET['head1'];
     $d=$_GET['msg1'];
     $dl=$_GET['ctdel']
$dl ="y";  

mysql_query("UPDATE  thirdpartycategorymaster SET  delete = '$dl' WHERE  thirdpartycategorymaster.ThirdPartyCategoryID ='$del' ");
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `;`

```
$dl=$_GET['ctdel']; <--- missing the ; here!!!
```

Comment: You should provide more info (table structure, what is "not working", do you get any errors, what are you trying to achieve etc etc). Maybe worth asking a different question.

Comment: When i execute update query in phpmyadmin it is working but when i put in a php file i click update it is not working.values are passed from back page

Comment: Check that your parameters are correctly passed and that quotes are escaped (and follow @Sarfraz advice to use `mysql_real_escape_string`). Echo the query string that you are passing to `mysql_query`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing semi-colon here:

```
$dl=$_GET['ctdel']
```

Should be:

```
include_once("db_conn.php");
 $del=$_GET['head1'];
     $d=$_GET['msg1'];
     $dl=$_GET['ctdel'];
$dl ="y";
```

---

## Note:

Make sure to use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function before your variables otherwise you are vulnerable to **SQL injection**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dl = $_GET['ctdel'];
$dl = "y";
```

If you add the missing ';'. But that means at the end $dl will contain 'y' and not $_GET['ctdel']. **The first line is overwritten by the second.**

So you're certainly missing something here :-)

Then effectively your code is not secure at all. And your database is certainly wrong as well, if delete is a column containing 'y' or 'n' it would certainly be better with booleans (or tinyint in MySQL), an utf8 encoded string to store a true/false value is certainly wrong.